# jQuery serializeObject function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a small serialization function which serializes form input to json.

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jdQfj/2/

I have currently no idea how to split up the array declarations let alone a combination of array and object declaration. However the function works good with infinite object nestings and normal values. But I could believe that there is optimization room.

```
jQuery.fn.serializeObject = function() {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();

    $.each(a, function() {

        // check if object
        if (this.name.indexOf('.') !== -1) {
            var path = this.name.split('.');

            var current = o;
            for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
                if (i === (path.length - 1)) {
                    current[path[i]] = this.value;
                } else {
                    if (current[path[i]] === undefined) {
                        current[path[i]] = {};
                    }
                }
                current = current[path[i]];
            }

        // check if array
        } else if (this.name.indexOf('[') !== -1 && this.name.indexOf(']')) {
            console.log(this.name + ' is an array');

            // has to get implmented

        // normal value
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value;
        }

    });

    return o;
};
```

Comment: I thought it would hard to know how the code works without an example. However when it helps you I can do ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
var addNestedPropToObj = function (obj, name, value) {
    var path = name.split('.'),
    current = obj,
    len = path.length - 1,
    i = 0;
    for (; i < len; i++) {
        current[path[i]] = current[path[i]] || {};
        current = current[path[i]];
    }
    if ( 0 < path[i].indexOf( "[]" ) ) {
        name = path[i].replace('[]', '');
        current[name] = current[name] || [];
        current[name].push(value);
    } else {
        current[path[i]] = value;
    }
    return obj;
};
jQuery.fn.serializeObject = function () {
    var o = {},
    a = this.serializeArray(),
    i = 0,
    len = a.length;
    for (; i < len; i++) {
        o = addNestedPropToObj(o, a[i].name, a[i].value);
    }
    return o;
};
```

[Demo and test cases](http://jsfiddle.net/jdQfj/3/)

Tips:

- Always try to separate most of the logic from the plugin into small testable functions.
- Use a regular loop instead of the `$.each()`.
- `String.prototype.split()` returns an array of the entire string if a match isn't found. So the else condition isn't required.

  ```
  // not needed
  else {
      o[this.name] = this.value;
  }
  ```
- Instead of checking to see if you're at the end of the loop, iterate to `path.length - 1` then afterwards perform the statement, `current[path[i]] = this.value;`.

As for the array format contained within the name property, for simplicity I suggest that the array notation should be an endpoint where the value is the push to the current property. So for a value to a added to an array, then `[]` must be at the end of the name.

Here's an example:

```
var func = function( str ){
    return JSON.stringify( addNestedPropToObj( {}, str, 1));
};
func("a[].b") === '{"a[]":{"b":1}}';
func("a.b[]") ===  '{"a":{"b":[1]}}';
```

Seen as an array: `a[]` or `a.b[]`

Seen as a string: `a[b]`, `a[b.c]`